# How to parse ISO string?

Tags: datetime, iso, python-dateutil

It doesn’t get parsed and just prints out the same ISO string that I’m trying to parse: `2/12/17 00:00:52`

What could I be doing wrong? Thank you in advance and will be sure to vote up and accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the representation of a `datetime` variable (that is the result of `dateutil.parser.parse`, btw) [is to print the ISO representation of the date.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.__str__)

However, if you store the variable instead of simply printing it after parsing it, you can print each individual part of the date:

```
date = dateutil.parser.parse("2017-02-16 22:11:05+00:00")
print(date.year)
2017

print(date.month)
2

print(date.day)
16

print(date.hour)
22

print(date.minute)
11

print(date.second)
5
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean it didn't parse... it did but then you asked to print it back out again it turns it back into a string:

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> date = dateutil.parser.parse("2017-02-16 22:11:05+00:00")
>>> repr(date)
'datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 16, 22, 11, 5, tzinfo=tzutc())'
>>> date.timetuple()
time.struct_time(tm_year=2017, tm_mon=2, tm_mday=16, tm_hour=22, 
                 tm_min=11, tm_sec=5, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=47, tm_isdst=0)
>>> str(date)
2017-02-16 22:11:05+00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll shamefully plug the library I use for datetime, `pendulum`.

```
import pendulum

parsed_time = pendulum.parse('2017-02-16 22:11:05+00:00')

parsed_time.to_formatted_date_string()
'Feb 16, 2017'
```

Theres a bunch more options as well, makes working with date time super easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to print it with only year, month, day, hour, minutes, and seconds, you could do this:

```
x=dateutil.parser.parse("2017-02-16 22:11:05+00:00")
print ("<%s>") % (x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d at %H:%M:%S'))
# Output <2017-02-16 at 22:11:05>
```